# Linebreak in multicolumn for column names in normal tabular environment

Tags: tables, line-breaking, tabularx, multicolumn

I saw many answers to this specific problem for `tabularx`-environment. But is it possible to split one column text in separate lines e.g. add a linebreak in a `mulitcolumn` in a `tabular` environment

This is what my table looks like so far :

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{Means of the key variable} 
  \label{} 
\small 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{1pt}} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} } 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{country} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{log\_w} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{s} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ycomp} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Change in yrs. of comp. school} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Age} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\% Males} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Nobs} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\% Complier} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Austria} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2.022} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{12.632} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8.679} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8 to 9} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{55.368} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.526} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{209} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.679} \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Belgium} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2.288} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{12.162} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8.005} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8 to 12} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{53.234} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.543} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{877} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.001} \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Denmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2.973} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{13.523} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7.115} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7 to 9} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{54.592} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.489} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{681} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.057} \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{France} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2.401} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{11.303} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8.64} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8 to 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{53.328} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.474} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{878} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.32} \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Germany} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2.58} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{14.705} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8.645} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8 to 9} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{55.309} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.51} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{857} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.645} \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Greece} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2.038} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{12.22} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6.148} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6 to 9} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{54.182} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.617} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{708} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.049} \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Italy} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2.196} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10.066} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7.112} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5 to 9} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{55.606} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.601} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{411} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.528} \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Netherlands} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2.748} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{13.289} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{9.02} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{9 to 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{54.69} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.535} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{910} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.02} \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Spain} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2.039} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{9.487} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8.671} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6 to 8} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{55.355} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.567} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{383} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.671} \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Sweden} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2.597} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{12.766} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7.154} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8 to 9} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{56.396} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.46} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1251} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.577} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Of course I will accept a solution with `tabularx` but since I have never used it I would recommend to stay in the `tabular` environment, if possible.

Comment: Why is each and every cell "wrapped" in a `\multicolumn{1}{c}` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose this variant solution with `siunitx`, `eqparbox`, `makecell` and `collcell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e, eqparbox}
\usepackage{siunitx, collcell, makecell}
\newcommand{\range}[1]{\eqparbox{ra}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\range}c<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\sisetup{table-format=1.3, table-number-alignment=center}
\centering
\caption{Means of the key variable\strut} \label{}
\small
\begin{tabular}{@{} l SS[table-format=2.3]SRS[table-format=2.3]SS[table-format=4]S @{}}
\toprule
Country & {log w} & {s} & {ycomp} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{Change in yrs.\\ of comp. school}}
 & {Age} & {\makecell{\%\\ Males}} & {Nobs} & {\makecell{\%\\ Complier}} \\
\midrule
Austria & 2.022 & 12.632 & 8.679 & 8 to 9 & 55.368 & 0.526 & 209 & 0.679 \\
Belgium & 2.288 & 12.162 & 8.005 & 8 to 12 & 53.234 & 0.543 & 877 & 0.001 \\
Denmark & 2.973 & 13.523 & 7.115 & 7 to 9 & 54.592 & 0.489 & 681 & 0.057 \\
France & 2.401 & 11.303 & 8.64 & 8 to 10 & 53.328 & 0.474 & 878 & 0.32 \\
Germany & 2.58 & 14.705 & 8.645 & 8 to 9 & 55.309 & 0.51 & 857 & 0.645 \\
Greece & 2.038 & 12.22 & 6.148 & 6 to 9 & 54.182 & 0.617 & 708 & 0.049 \\
Italy & 2.196 & 10.066 & 7.112 & 5 to 9 & 55.606 & 0.601 & 411 & 0.528 \\
Netherlands & 2.748 & 13.289 & 9.02 & 9 to 10 & 54.69 & 0.535 & 910 & 0.02 \\
Spain & 2.039 & 9.487 & 8.671 & 6 to 8 & 55.355 & 0.567 & 383 & 0.671 \\
Sweden & 2.597 & 12.766 & 7.154 & 8 to 9 & 56.396 & 0.46 & 1251 & 0.577 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good looking solution!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why each and every table cell is enclosed in a `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` wrapper.

I would (a) tailor the argument of the `D` column types to the characteristics of each column's numbers and (b) use a `tabularx` environment to allow line-wrapping in the table's header cells.

You may want to think of a shorter header than "Change in yrs.\ of comp.\ school".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp] 
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\caption{Means of the key variable\strut} \label{} 
\small 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l d{1.3} d{2.3} d{1.3} c 
                                   d{2.3} d{1.3} d{4.0} d{1.3} @{}} 
\toprule
Country & \mC{log w} & \mC{s} & \mC{ycomp} & \mC{Change in yrs.\ of comp.\ school} 
        & \mC{Age} & \mC{\% Males} & \mC{Nobs} & \mC{\% Complier} \\ 
\midrule 
Austria & 2.022 & 12.632 & 8.679 & 8 to 9 & 55.368 & 0.526 & 209 & 0.679 \\ 
Belgium & 2.288 & 12.162 & 8.005 & 8 to 12 & 53.234 & 0.543 & 877 & 0.001 \\ 
Denmark & 2.973 & 13.523 & 7.115 & 7 to 9 & 54.592 & 0.489 & 681 & 0.057 \\ 
France & 2.401 & 11.303 & 8.64 & 8 to 10 & 53.328 & 0.474 & 878 & 0.32 \\ 
Germany & 2.58 & 14.705 & 8.645 & 8 to 9 & 55.309 & 0.51 & 857 & 0.645 \\ 
Greece & 2.038 & 12.22 & 6.148 & 6 to 9 & 54.182 & 0.617 & 708 & 0.049 \\ 
Italy & 2.196 & 10.066 & 7.112 & 5 to 9 & 55.606 & 0.601 & 411 & 0.528 \\ 
Netherlands & 2.748 & 13.289 & 9.02 & 9 to 10 & 54.69 & 0.535 & 910 & 0.02 \\ 
Spain & 2.039 & 9.487 & 8.671 & 6 to 8 & 55.355 & 0.567 & 383 & 0.671 \\ 
Sweden & 2.597 & 12.766 & 7.154 & 8 to 9 & 56.396 & 0.46 & 1251 & 0.577 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx} 
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: The several multicolumn arguments were generated by `stargazer()` which is an automatic latex table production function for `R` but, as this is an good example for it, often not in a good way to do it in a good-lookig manner.

Comment: @mugdi - Thanks for providing the explanation for why each and every cell is encase in a `\multicolumn{1}{c}` wrapper. I suppose one might treat it as a starting step, but no more, toward producing a good-looking table.